# Core Data: To-many predicate ignored

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a `Group` <-->> `Member` relationship.  In `class Group: NSManagedObject {` I have the following properties:

```
@NSManaged public var members: Set<Member>

 public var status: Int16 {
    set {
        self.willChangeValue(forKey: "status")
        self.setPrimitiveValue(newValue, forKey: "status")
        self.didChangeValue(forKey: "status")
        self.members.removeAll()
    }
    get {
        self.willAccessValue(forKey: "status")
        var status: Int16 = 0
        if let statusKey = self.primitiveValue(forKey: "status") as? Int16 {
            self.didAccessValue(forKey: "status")
            status = statusKey
        }
        return status
    }
}
```

In `class Member: NSManagedObject` I have the following properties:

```
@NSManaged public var memberOf: Group?
@NSManaged public var status: Int16
```

Requirement: filter based on:
if `Groups.status = 1` AND `member.status = 1` (for each member)

I have the following code:

```
     let statusPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "status == %@", NSNumber(integerLiteral: 1))
     let statusMemberPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY members.status == %d", 1)
     let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.and, subpredicates: [statusPredicate, statusMemberPredicate])
     print("compoundPredicate \(compoundPredicate)")

     let requestGroups: NSFetchRequest<Group> = NSFetchRequest()
     requestGroups.entity = Group.entity()
     requestGroups.predicate = compoundPredicate
     requestGroups.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
     requestGroups.fetchBatchSize = 20
     frcGroup = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: requestGroups, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
     try? frcGroup?.performFetch()

     if let members = frcGroup?.fetchedObjects?.first?.members {
            for member in members{
                  print("member.status \(member.status)")
                }
             }
         }
```

I get the following Log:

```
compoundPredicate status == 1 AND ANY members.status == 1
member.status 0
member.status 1
member.status 0
```

I also tried the following and got the same log as above:

```
let statusMemberPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "members.status CONTAINS %d", 1)
```

It looks like it's fetching all of the `members` and ignoring the `members.status == 1` predicate.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate only determines whether the objects that are being fetched should be included in the results.  It has no effect on the related objects.  In your case, if a `Group` has `status` = 1, and any of its related `Member` objects has `status` = 1, then it will be included in the results.  But its `members` property is unaffected by the predicate.  It will include all the related members, even if they don't match the predicate.  So your results are what I would expect.

If you want to filter the `members`, you should do so separately after fetching the Group objects.

Comment: Thank you.  
1.  Isn't the `members` property for all of it's related `[Member]`?  
2.  How would I filter and attach it to the datasource after fetching `Group` objects if I am with `NSFetchedResultsController` with a `UITableView` ?

Comment: I just tried it.  What you described works; however, I have to manually keep track of `members`.  This defeats the purpose of using `NSFetchedResultsController`.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could make `Member` the subject of the fetch.  Then your predicate will be `status == 1 AND group.status == 1`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thank you!  Too bad there's not a better way to do this with to-many relationships.